# Dynamic button selection

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

Suppose I have two buttons that are ivar outlets. One is called "Blue" and the other "Red." Now, I have an NSString with the value of "Red." I want to set the button identified by the NSString to a `selected` state, without using `if`.

I do *not* want to do this:

```
NSString *button=@"Red";
if ([button isEqualtoString:@"Blue")
   self.blue.selected=YES; //self.blue and self.red are UIButtons
else
   self.red.selected=YES;
```

This is fine if you have two buttons, but I have quite a lot more than that, and it would be quite inelegant and cumbersome to do this for like 30 buttons.

I'd much rather find a way to directly link the name of a `UIButton` ivar to the value of an `NSString`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the string lower case and
you can use [KVC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/BasicPrinciples.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002170-178791) for that :

```
[self setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
    forKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.selected", button]];
```

Comment: how would you specifically indicate that it is the `selected` property of a button that is being set to `YES`?

Comment: @andrewjs: That's what the `.selected` in his key path indicates.

Comment: ah, it was the `self` at the beginning of this that was throwing me off. I'll give this a try.

Comment: I'm getting a warning in xcode followed by an exception crash surrounding the `numberWithBOOL` method; it says it is not found..

Comment: i see, it's `numberWithBool`, simple case problem threw it off.

Comment: yep, still getting exception errors on this. Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<projectViewController 0x15d1c0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key 50color.'

Comment: try declaring properties for your ivars in `projectViewController`. `@property...`

Answer (score 3):

You can put the buttons in a dictionary :

```
[NSDictionaryName addObject: UIButtonName forKey: @"blue"];
```

or something like that :

```
[NSDictionaryName objectForKey:@"blue"].selected = YES;
```

Comment: You'll actually want to use the normal message-passing syntax: `[[yourDictionary objectForKey:@"blue"] setSelected:YES]`. The dot syntax here will cause a type error, since `objectForKey:` isn't statically typed to return a UIButton.

Comment: this is cool too, although storying all those `UIButton` objects in the dictionary would be a tad of a pain also. I like Vince's other answer, but still not quite sure how to use it. Both helpful. thanks.

Comment: You'll have to cast the object you get from `objectForKey:` if you want to use the dot syntax on it. `((UIButton *)[myDictionary objectForKey:@"blue"]).selected = YES;`